# DAX expression to filter measure

Tags: dax

I have a measure that has been created called runningtotal.  I need to filter the returned dataset so that it is filtered by a specific column.

Code below:

```
Running Total = 

 IF(
                    fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key] = 10 && 
                    CONTAINSSTRING(
                        fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number],
                        "-"
                    ),
                    0,
                    if(COUNTX(
                        FILTER(
                            fact_sales_order_line,
                            fact_sales_order_line[part_key] = EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[part_key]) &&
                            fact_sales_order_line[formatted_ship_date] >= EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key]) &&
                            fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key] < EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key]) &&
                            RELATED(fact_sales_order_header[Drop Ship Formatted]) <> "YES" && fact_sales_order_line[Future Order] = "No" &&
                            CONCATENATE(fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key]
                                ,CONCATENATE(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number],fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_line])) <>   
                            CONCATENATE(EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key])
                                ,CONCATENATE(EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number]),EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_line])))
                        ),
                        fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number]
                    ) > 0,
                    SUMX(
                        FILTER(
                            fact_sales_order_line,
                            fact_sales_order_line[part_key] = EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[part_key]) &&
                            fact_sales_order_line[formatted_ship_date] >= EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key]) &&
                            fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key] < EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key]) &&
                            RELATED(fact_sales_order_header[Drop Ship Formatted]) <> "YES" && fact_sales_order_line[Future Order] = "No" &&
                            CONCATENATE(fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key]
                                ,CONCATENATE(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number],fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_line])) <>   
                            CONCATENATE(EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key])
                                ,CONCATENATE(EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number]),EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_line])))
                        ),
                        fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_quantity]
                    ),0)
                )
```

The filter I need to filter the entire dataset is:

```
 FILTER('fact_sales_order_status',fact_sales_order_status[sales_order_status_key] <> 57
```

How would I implement this?

Tried implementing the code as follows:

```
 FILTER ('fact_sales_order_status',fact_sales_order_status[sales_order_status_key] <> 57 &&
    IF(
                        fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key] = 10 && 
                        CONTAINSSTRING(
                            fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number],
                            "-"
                        ),
                        0,  FILTER('fact_sales_order_status',fact_sales_order_status[sales_order_status_key] <> 57   &&                     if(COUNTX(
                            FILTER(
                                fact_sales_order_line,
                                fact_sales_order_line[part_key] = EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[part_key]) &&
                                fact_sales_order_line[formatted_ship_date] >= EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key]) &&
                                fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key] < EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key]) &&
                                RELATED(fact_sales_order_header[Drop Ship Formatted]) <> "YES" && fact_sales_order_line[Future Order] = "No" &&
                                CONCATENATE(fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key]
                                    ,CONCATENATE(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number],fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_line])) <>   
                                CONCATENATE(EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key])
                                    ,CONCATENATE(EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number]),EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_line])))
                            ),
                            fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number]
                        ) > 0,
                        SUMX(
                            FILTER(
                                fact_sales_order_line,
                            fact_sales_order_line[part_key] = EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[part_key]) &&
                            fact_sales_order_line[formatted_ship_date] >= EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key]) &&
                            fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key] < EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key]) &&
                            RELATED(fact_sales_order_header[Drop Ship Formatted]) <> "YES" && fact_sales_order_line[Future Order] = "No" &&
                            CONCATENATE(fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key]
                                ,CONCATENATE(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number],fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_line])) <>   
                            CONCATENATE(EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key])
                                ,CONCATENATE(EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number]),EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_line])))
                        ),
                        fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_quantity]
                    ),0)
                )))
```

Then I get an error "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value"

Comment: This is a Calculated Column not a measure - right?

Comment: Calculated column.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Running Total = 
  var solFilter = 
    FILTER(
      fact_sales_order_line,
      fact_sales_order_line[part_key] = EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[part_key]) &&
      fact_sales_order_line[formatted_ship_date] >= EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key]) &&
      fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key] < EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[order_date_key]) &&
      RELATED(fact_sales_order_header[Drop Ship Formatted]) <> "YES" && fact_sales_order_line[Future Order] = "No" &&
      CONCATENATE(fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key]
        ,CONCATENATE(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number],fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_line])) <>   
      CONCATENATE(EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key])
        ,CONCATENATE(EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number]),EARLIER(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_line])))
    )

  var solCount =
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTX(solFilter, fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number]),
      fact_sales_order_status[sales_order_status_key] <> 57
    )

  var solSum =
    CALCULATE(
      SUMX(solFilter, fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_quantity]),
      fact_sales_order_status[sales_order_status_key] <> 57
    )

  RETURN
    IF(
      fact_sales_order_line[business_unit_key] = 10 &&
      CONTAINSSTRING(fact_sales_order_line[sales_order_number], "-"),
      0,
      IF(solCount > 0, solSum, 0)
    )
```